# How to separate lookup column selected items with "X"?

Tags: sharepoint-online, lookup-column, multiple-values

I have a SharePoint Lookup column with multiple choices, as follows:

Apple
Orange
Strawberry
Watermelon

How can I populate a different column by separating the choices with "X", as follows:

Apple X Orange X Strawberry

OR

Strawberry X Watermelon

Comment: Have you thought of using [JSON column formatting](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/declarative-customization/column-formatting)? You can format multi-select column using ForEach construct

Answer (score 1):

Here is a sample of JSON formatting for multi-choice column to produce the expected result.

```
{
  "$schema": "https://developer.microsoft.com/json-schemas/sp/v2/column-formatting.schema.json",
  "elmType": "div",
  "style": {
    "display": "block"
  },
  "children": [
    {
      "elmType": "span",
      "forEach": "fruit in @currentField",
      "txtContent": {
        "operator": "?",
        "operands": [
          "=loopIndex('fruit') == 0",
          "[$fruit.lookupValue]",
          "=' X ' + [$fruit.lookupValue]"
        ]
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

[image]